# Inconsistent results of using indexOf on an array in an if-statment

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, indexof

I am in the process of learning node. The following code is giving me inconsistent result ie, if i give `argv1.indexOf('test')`, then the code is unable to find the text, but, some time it is returning true. Why is it so.

```
function process(argv1) {
    if(argv1.indexOf('test')) {
        console.log('Text is available in array.');
    }
}
process(['test','one','help', 'one', 'two']);
```

Comment: What would you expect `indexOf` to return in this case?

Comment: Did you bother to read the documentation for `indexOf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `indexOf` returns an index of matched element. If element not found, it will return `-1`.

What you need is to change the condition:

```
function process(argv1) {
    if(argv1.indexOf('test') !== -1) {
        console.log('Text is available in array.');
    }
}
process(['test','one','help', 'one', 'two']);
```

**Edit**: As pointed out @Havvy, in case of `test`, `.indexOf` will return `0` which would be casted to `false`. For other array elements, their indices would be converted to `true`, as any non zero numbers would be casted to `true`. More about javascript evaluation you can read [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/).

Comment: Furthermore, `if` will typecast the result to a boolean. The value `0` gets typecasted to `false`, so `['test', 'foo', bar'].indexOf('test')` evaluates to `0`, and `if (0) {}` evaluates to false, not executing your block.

Comment: Yeah, of course, and if the element index would be more than zero, it would cast to `true`.